# Create objects with values and add to a map

Tags: java

I have the following Sample object being created and adding it to a map as follows.

Is there a way I could have added these set values to Sample object without having to create

an object and directly add it to the map?

Note that I can't change Sample class thus can't be adding constructors nor builder pattern in there.

I am using Java 8

The following works where I create the Sample object and assign it to a variable first and then

add it to a map.

```
Sample SampleHeader = new Sample();
SampleHeader.setOrder(null);
SampleHeader.setHeader(HEADER_DATA);
data.getAllSamples().put("info", SampleHeader);
```

Looking for something like this (syntatically wrong)

```
data.getAllSamples().put(
    "info", new Sample().setOrder(null).setHeader(HEADER_DATA)
);
```

Comment: Well if you return `this` in your setter methods then you *could* do `data.getAllSamples().put("info", new Sample().setOrder(null).setHeader(HEADER_DATA));`

Comment: @xtratic I can't change that class as mentioned. :)

Comment: Why don't you create a separate factory class or a separate builder class and use that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a builder, like this, to allow you to create the object via method chaining:

```
public class SampleBuilder {
    private Sample sample = new Sample();

    public SampleBuilder setHeader(Object header) {
        sample.setHeader(header);
        return this;
    }

    public SampleBuilder setOrder(Object order) {
        sample.setOrder(order);
        return this;
    }

    public Sample build() {
        Sample built = sample;
        sample = new Sample();
        return built;
    }

    // OR this
    public static Sample build(Object header, Object order) {
        Sample built = new Sample();
        built.setHeader(header);
        built.setOrder(order);
        return built;
    }
}
```

Then you can call:

```
    data.getAllSamples().put(
        "info", new SampleBuilder().setOrder(null).setHeader(HEADER_DATA).build()
    );
    // OR this
    data.getAllSamples().put(
        "info", new SampleBuilder(null, HEADER_DATA).build()
    );
```